# Checking after or before include files

Tags: php

Is it faster to check before including files, or is it faster to put the checking inside the files themselves? Or are there no differences? So for example:

**version 1:**

```
-test1.php-

if ($true) {
include("test2.php");
}

-test2.php-

//long codes
```

**version 2:**

```
-test1.php-

include("test2.php");

-test2.php-

if ($true) {
//long codes
}
```

So, is version 1 faster, or version 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$true` is false, then the first version will not have to open `test2.php` or parse the code in it, so it will be faster.

If it's true, there's little performance difference between them. Both versions have to read and parse both files.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're looking to compare two different methods for speed, you can perform a simple test by starting a timer at the beginning of your code and then seeing how much time has passed after the code has finished running. For example:

```
<?php
$start_time = microtime(true);

// your code

$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "\n\nRuntime: ".($end_time - $start_time)." seconds.";
?>
```

Just do that for each version and see which one takes less time. I use this  trick *everywhere*. Over time, you will begin to develop your own sense about which methods are the most efficient.